# Dynamically changing input field in AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I'm stuck on something I haven't run across before. I have the following code in my Laravel project:

```
<div class="claimDocuments">
                @foreach($claim->attachments as $ca)
                    @if(Storage::mimeType($ca->attachmentPath) == "application/pdf")
                        <div class="document">
                            <a href="{{Storage::disk('local')->url($ca->attachmentPath)}}">
                            <img src="/images/Circle-icons-document.svg.png" class="img-circle" alt="Shipment" height="80px" width="80px"><br>
                            </a>
                            <div class="documentTitle">


     <span class="fa fa-check"></span>
                                    <input value="{{$ca->title}}" class="form-control" name="title" type="text">
<input value="{{$ca->id}}" class="form-control" name="attachmentID" type="text">
                                </div>

                            </div>

                    @endif
                @endforeach
                </div>
```

So basically there can be multiple ".document"'s in my page. There's an input field with a checkmark in it and I would like to change the value in my database solely by typing in a new value and clicking the checkmark.

The problem is, I would like to do this with AJAX, but I'm not all too familiar with `this`'s and such.

So what would be the appropriate way to click the checkmark and have something similar to the below code be triggered?

```
$.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/carrier/claims/files/updateFile',
            data: {
                'attachmentID': $('input[name=attachmentID]').val(),
                'title': $('input[name=title]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {......
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really add a more specific class to the "checkmark" you are mentioning.

A solution is to listen for clicks on the checkmarks. When one of them is clicked, you "go up" to its `div.document` (via `.closest()`) parent and then find all the inputs from there (below that parent, via `.find()`).

Using the `span`'s classes how they are now, it'd be something like:

```
$("span.fa.fa-check").click(function () {
  var checkMarkSpan = $(this);
  var parentDocumentDiv = checkMarkSpan.closest("div.document");

  // now do the Ajax. Notice how the inputs are searched below the div, not everywhere ($)
  $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: '/carrier/claims/files/updateFile',
            data: {
                'attachmentID': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=attachmentID]').val(),
                'title': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=title]').val(),
               '_token': parentDocumentDiv.find('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
            ...

});
```

Of course, if the "checkmark" is not the `<span class="fa fa-check"></span>` but something else, change the `"span.fa.fa-check"` to it.